# SBT - watch different sources depending on Task

Tags: sbt, scala.js

In a cross Scala JS server / client project, I want changes of some sources to restart the server and other sources to trigger the packaging process, but without the restart. Different tasks will not help because they will simply do one or the other and I want both at the same time.

In more detail:
I've got a Scala.js crossProject. I'm using the following to ensure the server can serve the built JavScript:

```
val app = crossProject.settings(...)
lazy val appJS = app.js
lazy val jsFile = fastOptJS in(appJS, Compile)
lazy val appJVM = app.jvm.settings(
  (resources in Compile) += jsFile.value.data,
  (resources in Compile) += jsFile.value.data.toPath.resolveSibling(jsFile.value.data.name+".map").toFile,
  (resources in Compile) += (packageJSDependencies in(appJS, Compile)).value
)
```

If I run `~ appJVM/compile:packageBin::packageConfiguration` then changes to the JavaScript source are immediately compiled and placed in the appJVM target/classes dir, so a refresh of the browser gets my new code - brilliant.

However, I would also like to use the sbt-revolver plugin to restart the server if I edit server-side code. But there's the rub - if I use `~ ;appJVM/compile:packageBin::packageConfiguration;appJVM/reStart` then changes to the client side source restart the server, which I don't want. But if I remove the client side project from the transitive watch then it no longer notices if I change the client side project.

Is there a way to define watchTransitiveSources differently per task?

Comment: More generally - I'd quite like not to use ```~``` at all, and instead to create a task that watches an arbitrary set of files and runs some other task each time they change, but my googling is letting me down - I can't find an example of someone doing this.

Comment: I think your question could be written simpler. Also, don't imply the answer, but describe your need. If I understand correctly you want changes of some sources to restart the server and other sources to trigger the packaging process, but without the restart. Different tasks will not help because they will simply do one or the other and you want both in the same time. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I will alter my opening paragraph to your wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` is actually a command that watches the transitive sources of the base project and then synchronously runs everything passed as an argument to it when those change, before re-running the original input (including ~). It does not make any information about what has changed available to those command line inputs (difficult to see how it could).

Consequently the solution I came to is to write a new watch command. It also needs to watch all sources, but then conditionally choose what to do based on which files have changed.

I've hacked something ugly as anything together that does this, but will look at making it more legible, general, tested and a Plugin. However, in the meantime anyone trying to follow my path can use this public gist: https://gist.github.com/LeisureMonitoringAdmin/0eb2e775e47b40f07d9e6d58d17b6d52

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using `sbt-resolver` not `sbt-revolver` ?

Because the second one allows controlling the `triggered` resources using

- `watchSources` - defines the files for a single project that are
  monitored for changes. By default, a project watches resources and
  Scala and Java sources.
- `watchTransitiveSources` - then combines the
  `watchSources` for the current project and all execution and classpath
  dependencies (see [.scala build definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Full-Def.html) for details on interProject
  dependencies).

*Source: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Triggered-Execution.html*

Comment: Yes, sbt-revolver - typo.

I've read the docs. They don't cover my problem - watching a _different_ set of sources depending on the task for the same project.